# Powershell/CMD continuous ping to file which is overwritten after X days

Tags: networking, command-line, powershell, ping

I've found a lot of examples of continuous ping and saving output to a file. But what i was hoping to find was how do I have the script rewrite the output file after every 7 days, thereby eliminating the need for intervention.

**Purpose**: The idea is to run this script from a windows server and have it ping 8.8.8.8 every 30 seconds to check internet connectivity and log it to a file which is stored for 7 days and on the 8th day the script should start rewriting from line 1.

I only have the basic script:

Powershell:

```
ping -t 8.8.8.8|Foreach{"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_} > c:\ping\test.txt
```

CMD:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 –t |cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!date! !time! !data!)&ping -n 2 8.8.8.8>nul" >>"C:\ping\TEST.txt"
```

Comment: It seems you would benefit far more for using a program such as MultiPing, or PingPlotter, tools designed to ping, measure and log connectivity.

Comment: But if this script is really what you want, then the best approach is to ping and append to existing file on a continuious loop, but append to a file with the date of today in the name. That way, you get a log file for each day. With forfiles /d -7 you can delete files older than 7 days.

Comment: @Naas ... Consider having each day log to it's own `ScriptProcessName_YYYYMMDD.log`, and then have a second job that runs daily and deletes all the logs that are older than 3 days. This way your process logs with append for the full day to the same log and then logging after 12 midnight for that same running process logs to its new `<YYYYMMDD>` named log file. Sounds like and easy and simple solution, control your logging process a little differently to accommodate for your need.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be to use the Task Scheduler to put this
script into a task that is scheduled to run weekly.

The task should start with deleting the file, then creating a new one.

Some small points:

- Use
  [sleep](https://ss64.com/nt/sleep.html)
  for waiting 30 seconds inside the loop
- Use the `>>` indirection
- Use an account for the task that can use the network.

[image]